# In Processmaker 4, can I search for requests or tasks using the valued introduced in the forms?

Tags: processmaker

I was wondering if in the Processmaker 4 interface there is the possibility of searching for requests or tasks that with certain values in the requests values.

In advanced search it seems that you can query using environment variables but I need to be able to locate a request or process using information introduced in the forms.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that processmaker has a query language that can be used in the process search box to search processes containing specific form data.
Por example if we wished to search for a process related with invoice 2222 and the field containing the invoice number was named Invoice_number, the query to use in the search would be:

```
data.Invoice_number = "2222"
```